# Unable to navigate the datepicker in a Mercurytravels.co.in website

Tags: java, selenium, date, datepicker, webdriver

I am looking at suggestions to navigate through the datepicker in the https://www.mercurytravels.co.in/flights application (i'm new to selenium). I would like to pass the date in "DD/MM/YYYY" format and then be able to select the date from the "Date of Journey" date picker element.

Any suggestions/recommendations on how it would be possible to select a specific date in coming months from the date element?

Comment: Since you didn't show us what have YOU tried and what exact problems did you faced the general answer is: you should write some code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use SImpleDateFormat java lib for formatting the date.

```
SimpleDateFormat st = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
st.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
return st.format(new Date());
```